# How can I reference a td to another td with similar classes in the same tr?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
const orgDates = $('.classdate');
orgDates.each((i, elem) => {
  let parts = $(elem).text().split('/');
  let dt = new Date(parts[2], parts[0] - 1, parts[1]).getTime();
  let diffdate = Math.floor((dt - new Date().getTime()) / (86400 *
    1000));
  if (isNaN(diffdate) || dt > new Date().getTime()) {
    return 0;
  }
  if ((diffdate + 2) < 1) {
    if ((diffdate + 2) == 0) {
      diffdate = (diffdate + 1) + ' day ago';
    } else {
      diffdate = (diffdate + 1) + ' days ago';
    }
  }
  diffdate = diffdate.toString().slice(1);
  alert('date:' + $(elem).text() + ' ' + diffdate);
});
```

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
  moment().format();
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>colors</th>
    <th>animals</th>
    <th>genres</th>
    <th>dates</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row1">
    <td>red</td>
    <td class="animal">cat</td>
    <td>horror</td>
    <td class="classdate">11/12/2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row2">
    <td>orange</td>
    <td class="animal">dog</td>
    <td>comedy</td>
    <td class="classdate">10/7/2018</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row3">
    <td>yellow</td>
    <td class="animal">goat</td>
    <td class="first">drama</td>
    <td class="classdate">1/3/2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row4">
    <td>green</td>
    <td class="animal">otter</td>
    <td>action</td>
    <td class="classdate"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to loop through every td in the dates column but only use dates in the past. So future dates or blanks are ignored. Then based off of the dates I need I want to make an  alert that has the date and the animal from the same row.
For example 'date: ' + 'classdate2' + 'animal2' + 'some more text'.
So because classdate3 is in the future I want to skip it and it's associated animal3.
The row and the two td's that I need all end in the same number.
So far I am able to loop through the dates and check the diff between it and now, ignore future dates and blanks, and alert the dates and how many days past today. Is there a way to do this or should I try an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can use functions like `.closest()` and `.siblings()` to find related elements.

```
$(elem).closest("tr")
```

will return the row that contains the current element in the loop, and

```
$(elem).siblings(".animal")
```

will return the `<td class="animal">` in the same row.

You should remove all the digits from the classes when you do this, the point of classes is to assign the same class to elements that should be processed similarly.

Comment: The increment class thing was just an idea. I've been at this for a while and am getting kind of frustrated. I'm confused how the correct animal will be paired with the correct classdate if I don't use every classdate?

Comment: What's confusing you? The correct animal is a sibling of the classdate, so `.siblings` finds it.